# (IOS) When i want to make a button disable in a cell, its make many other disable

Tags: ios, button, tags, sender

I am making an ios app. My issue is when I want to make a button disable in a cell, its make many other disable. I try many issue but I really don't know why. Tag of the button are ok, I think I don't use sender correctly. My code look like this :

```
- (IBAction) fiyeItPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
    UIButton *fiyeItButton = (UIButton*) sender;

    [fiyeItButton setEnabled:NO];
    NSLog(@"%d",[fiyeItButton tag]);

    NSString *FiyeNumberString = [playlistVote objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    int FiyeInt = [FiyeNumberString intValue] + 1;
    FiyeNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",FiyeInt];
    [playlistVote  replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:FiyeNumberString];

    [self saveForTable];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    PlaylistTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.SongName.text = [playlistSongTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.ArtisteName.text = [playlistSongArtist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.numberOfVote.text = [playlistVote objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.VoteButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How do you make a button disable in a cell (your code)?

Comment: Like this : in the fiyeit button action [fiyeItButton setEnabled:NO];

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reusing TableView cells this means that when you start scrolling in the TableView, the cell with the disabled  button will eventually get reused and shown. What you need to do is to actively set the button to enabled or disabled in CellForRowAtIndexPath.

I suggest you keep track of which indexes the button has been pressed on, and then use that information to determine whether the button should be enabled or disabled in the CellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what you already have, it seems like the simplest 'quick fix' would be just to have another array like playlistSongTitle etc.

Which all it would need to do is have some bools to keep track of if the button was enabled or not. Then in you cellForRowAtIndexPath: method all you would need is.

```
[cell.voteButton setEnabled:[playlistButtonsEnabled objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

You may need to extract the bool first not sure if it will correctly infer the type.
Then in the fiyeItPressed: method just adjust the BOOL to YES or NO.

Hope this helps